# Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: junk after document element line 3, column 4

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

dynamixel_controllersTutorialsCreatingmetacontroller

I want to connect the dynamixel AX-64 motor with the PC, however, when I follow the tutorials and create a meta controller, I come across the following question.
I start the controller using the following command.

```
roslaunch my_dynamixel_tutorial start_meta_controller.launch
```

the `start_meta_controller.launch` file is

```
<!-- Start tilt joint controller -->
<rosparam file="$(find my_dynamixel_tutorial)/tilt.yaml" command="load"/>
    <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="dynamixel_controllers" type="controller_spawner.py"
          args="--manager=dxl_manager
                --port dxl_USB0
                joint1_controller                       
                joint2_controller

                "
          output="screen"/>

 <!-- Start joints trajectory controller controller -->
    <rosparam file="$(find my_dynamixel_tutorial)/joints_trajectory_controller.yaml" command="load"/>
    <node name="controller_spawner_meta" pkg="dynamixel_controllers" type="controller_spawner.py"
          args="--manager=dxl_manager
                --type=meta
                f_arm_controller
                joint1_controller
                joint2_controller
                                                
                "           
                          output="screen"/>
```

And the error is:

```
… logging to /home/acer/.ros/log/63b699b2-a98e-11e7-b094-28e34739f5b2/roslaunch-acer-ubuntu-5609.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: junk after document element: line 3, column 4
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

How to solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276603/invalid-roslaunch-xml-syntax:-junk-after-document-element-line-3,-column-4/) by [JeffJeff](https://answers.ros.org/users/32746/jeffjeff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If that is indeed your full launch file, it is missing the (opening) `<launch>` and (closing) `</launch>` tags around all launch XML code.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0